# How can I extend the paperjs's static constructors?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

PaperJS has many static constructors (like Rectangle) on their base constructor functions such as Shape. I'd like to extend one of those static constructors like this,

```
class Rect extends paper.Shape.Rectangle {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
    }

    customMethod() {}
}

const A = new Rect();
```

But what I get in variable A is an instance of class "Shape" which doesn't have the "customMethod".

What is a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paper.js don't seem to use standard ecmascript
classes; their class system is based on
[straps.js](https://github.com/lehni/straps.js/).
You can see it in action
in the source code of [Rectangle.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/basic/Rectangle.js),
that is the class available as `paper.Rectangle`.

If you wanted to extend `Rectangle`, you could
use its method `.extend`, like this:

```js
const Rect = paper.Rectangle.extend({
   customMove(dx, dy){
      this.x += dx;
      this.y += dy;
   }
});

const rect = new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
rect.customMove(30, 10);
```

As for `Shape.Rectangle` it can't
be properly *extended*, since it is just
a method of the class `Shape` - see
the [source code](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/item/Shape.js#L530).

You could extend `Shape` itself to add a new static
method:

```js
const Shape1 = paper.Shape.extend({
   statics:{
      Rect(){
         //... access to this.Rectangle
      }
   }
});
```

And in some cases, it is feasible to just add
a new method directly to `Shape`:

```js
paper.Shape.Rect = function(){
    //... access this.Rectangle, or paper.Shape.Rectangle)
}
```